# Reflection in a lake

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Suppose there is lake. And a cloud is at a height h above it. The reflection of the cloud will be at the same depth in the lake as the height of the cloud or at the surface of the lake or at the base of the lake or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the last time you looked in a mirror. Did your reflection look like it was closer to the mirror, farther from the mirror, or the same distance as you?  The same will be true for the cloud.

There may be refraction that takes place inside the lake, but since you are looking at the reflection of the clouds off the surface, the lake behaves as a plane mirror.  Object distance and image distance are equal in this case.  The height of the cloud is the object distance in this case.

Comment: Important to remember that this is a virtual image. The light rays "appear" to come from the image. So depth of the lake or a thickness of the mirror do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The surface of the lake is most reflective due to the contrast in colors and our minds perception of the image. The interior of the water has reflective qualities as well although the difference in densities of air and water and distance will cause refracted images to render with a lack of uniformity.